# ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost + Segmentation Fault on docker daemon

Tags: services, docker, raspberrypi, pip

I installed docker at my raspberry pi zero w running the latest raspbian with

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

and docker-compose with

```
sudo pip install docker-compose
```

When I run docker-compose in my raspberry:

```
sudo docker-compose up
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

When I do `sudo dockerd`:

```
sudo dockerd
Segmentation fault
```

It seems that the docker daemon is not working because of the Segmentation Fault. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's a known issue with 18.09 and ARMv6 processors.  Discussion and downgrade instructions here:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/38175

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Link-only answers are discuraged here (what if the link goes dead or is moved somewhere else?). Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1093503/edit) your answer and explain the step needed to resolve the issue.